# AdMob banner isn't working iOS9

Tags: ios, objective-c, admob

I'm working on my app, I wanted to add AdMob banner like I always do without any problem before, but now on this new app it doesn't show up.

The banner ad is in one of the `UITableViewCell`'s, and I get this log message:

```
-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "kindle://home" - error: "(null)"
```

I have disabled Bitcode and I have added the App Transport Security and `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` in the `info.plist` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update to the [latest AdMob SDK](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/download?hl=en). This issue was fixed in 7.5.0:

> SDK no longer uses `UIApplication`'s `canOpenURL` method on iOS 9 devices.

[AdMob for iOS Release Notes](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/rel-notes)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but when I added it to the pod file I got : 
[!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:

- `Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK (~> 7.5.0)` required by `Podfile`

Answer (score 0):

I simply pasted this into my `info.plist` file and it all worked

```xml
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

as per https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/ios9